# Throws exception: “error: Class java.nio.channels.ReadPendingException not found” when compile jetty project with maven

Tags: scala, maven, jetty

I use jetty as an embedded part of my project. When I use maven to compile my test project, it throws exception below:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jetty-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jettytest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /workspaces/JettyTest/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ jettytest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default) @ jettytest ---
[INFO] /workspaces/JettyTest/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /workspaces/JettyTest/target/classes at 1440407546804
[WARNING] warning: Class java.nio.channels.ReadPendingException not found - continuing with a stub.
[ERROR] error: Class java.nio.channels.ReadPendingException not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] warning: Class java.nio.channels.WritePendingException not found - continuing with a stub.
[ERROR] error: Class java.nio.channels.WritePendingException not found - continuing with a stub.
[WARNING] two warnings found
[ERROR] two errors found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.820 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-24T17:12:30+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default) on project jettytest: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

A part of pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.scala-lang.version>2.11.6</org.scala-lang.version>
    <jettyVersion>9.3.2.v20150730</jettyVersion>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- scala -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${org.scala-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My test code looks like below(Scala):

```
    val server = new Server()

    val connector = new ServerConnector(server)
    connector.setHost("localhost")
    connector.setPort(8080)
    connector.setIdleTimeout(30000)

    // Set a connector
    server.addConnector(connector)

    val context = new ContextHandler()
    context.setContextPath("/")
    context.setHandler(new HelloHandler())

    // Set a handler
    server.setHandler(context)

    // Start the server
    server.start()
    server.join()
```

I found that if I reduce code like below, It can compile successful. It seems like throws exception when compile the ServerConnector. But the error message seems not the real reason which compile failed. Anyone can help me?

```
    val server = new Server()

    val context = new ContextHandler()
    context.setContextPath("/")
    context.setHandler(new HelloHandler())

    // Set a handler
    server.setHandler(context)

    // Start the server
    server.start()
    server.join()
```

$mvn --version

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-15T01:29:23+08:00)
Maven home: /Users/wanbo/server/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: EUC_CN
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not compiling with Java 8.

Comment: My java environment below:
    java version "1.8.0_31"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: Edit your question, and add the output of `$ mvn --version` to the end.

Comment: I have added, and set the Java ("1.8.0_31") for maven. Now, It works. Thanks Joakim!